# What is the purpose of ROWLOCK on Delete and when should I use it?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ex)

When should I use this statement:

```
DELETE TOP (@count)
FROM ProductInfo WITH (ROWLOCK)
WHERE ProductId = @productId_for_del;
```

And when should be just doing:

```
DELETE TOP (@count)
FROM ProductInfo
WHERE ProductId = @productId_for_del;
```

Comment: Don't use hints unless you really have yo and know what the possible consequences are.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The `with (rowlock)` is a hint that instructs the database that it should keep locks on a row scope. That means that the database will avoid escalating locks to block or table scope.

You use the hint when only a single or only a few rows will be affected by the query, to keep the lock from locking rows that will not be deleted by the query. That will let another query read unrelated rows at the same time instead of having to wait for the delete to complete.

If you use it on a query that will delete a lot of rows, it may degrade the performance as the database will try to avoid escalating the locks to a larger scope, even if it would have been more efficient.

Normally you shouldn't need to add such hints to a query, because the database knows what kind of lock to use. It's only in situations where you get performance problems because the database made the wrong decision, that you should add such hints to a query.

Comment: Would you suggest to use it on a delete statement that deletes 2000 rows at a time in a loop?

Comment: The database should be able to make the decision on its own.  It will escalate if it sees a good reason to.  I would avoid over-ruling it (which is what a hint does) unless I have a good reason to, like if I know something that the database doesn't.

Comment: @Brandon: Yes, that is a good point. Normally the database knows what lock to use, much better than a programmer ever could.

Comment: You may find this hint useful when performing deleting by non covered in another index column and in multiple threads. In my case I was facing multiple deadlocks cause of pagelock. Unfortunately mssql 2012 decided to ignore the hint in my case and went again for pagelocks. I've ended with disabling pagelocks on clustered index.

Comment: [Hints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query?view=sql-server-ver15): _“Because the SQL Server Query Optimizer typically selects the best execution plan for a query, we recommend only using hints as a last resort for experienced developers and database administrators.”_

Answer (score 12):

Rowlock is a query hint that should be used with caution (as is all query hints).

Omitting it will likely still result in the exact same behaviour and providing it will not guarantee that it will only use a rowlock, it is only a hint afterall. If you do not have a very in depth knowledge of lock contention chances are that the optimizer will pick the best possible locking strategy, and these things are usually best left to the database engine to decide.

ROWLOCK means that SQL will lock only the affected row, and not the entire table or the page in the table where the data is stored when performing the delete. This will only affect other people reading from the table at the same time as your delete is running.

If a table lock is used it will cause all queries to the table to wait until your delete has completed, with a row lock only selects reading the specific rows will be made to wait.

Deleting top N where N is a number of rows will most likely lock the table in any case.

Answer (score -3):

SQL Server defaults to page locks. This is the most efficient way for SQL server to process multiple date sets.  But SQL server is not multi-user friendly sometimes; therefore you may need to incorporate locking methods so you can get your data to flow in and out of the database.  This is why people approach that problem by using locking hints.

If everyone designed there database tables so that everything processed each row at page width - the system would be very fast.  But no one spends that detailed amount of time.

So, you might see people use with(nolock) on their SELECT statements and the use of with(rowlock) on their UPDATE and DELETE statements.  An INSERT does not matter because it will lock the PAGE automatically.  Sometimes by using with(rowlock), you can get better multi-user (multiple user connections) performance.

The problem with(nolock) is that you can return the committed record sitting there in the DB already, plus the dirty record that is about to update the sitting record; thus a double return of records to your SELECT statement. If you know the personality of your system on how the data runs through it, you can use with(nolock) to your advantage quite a bit though.

When do you know when to use with(rowlock)? When your system isn't letting user play nice with each other in the same table / record.  Though, query re-write / tune first and then adjust your locking as a last resort.

But as a DBA, always blame the developer's code.  It is your solemnly sworn duty to do such.  If you are the developer writing this code, just blame yourself.

Comment: "SQL Server defaults to page locks." is not a correct statement. [The SQL Server Database Engine uses a dynamic locking strategy that automatically chooses the best locking granularity for queries in most cases.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-ver15#Customize)

Comment: And the info about insert locking pages is also wrong and that about nolock also suffers from misapprehensions so not seeing much of actual value in this answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer is generally not correct, and I don't think answers the question.  Also I can't tell if it is sarcasm [reading the last line].  I will agree only with "re-write your query before playing with locking hints"  NOLOCK statement is half-true.  In SQL Server 7 or 2000 maybe I'd agree.  Version 2005 introduced a better locking mechanism (and row versioning) that prevents many of the lock escalation issues that 2000 had, that was 22+ years ago.  Pro/Cons of NOLOCK is a book of it's own - while I prefer row versioning (RCS) over NOLOCK, NOLOCK is a cheap and easy fix.